# How to tracking an object with eye in hand pan/tilt robot using pid controller and depth camera

Tags: arduino, pid, vision-opencv

I have a problem in my thesis, that is the stepper motor is limited in movement when following an object, the second problem is that when I use the pid controller, the center of the color image ( is a fixed point) does not coincide with the center point of the circle (circle is the shape I am using to track), currently I don't know how to solve the above problems, please help me. I am using 2 stepper motors, 1 depth camera intel d435, 1 arduino uno

Here is the code python on computer:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyrealsense2 as rs
from simple_pid import PID
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
import math

# Lấy danh sách các cổng serial khả dụng
available_ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())

# Tìm kiếm cổng chứa "Arduino" trong tên
arduino_port = None
for port in available_ports:
    if "Arduino" in port.description:
        arduino_port = port.device
        break

# Kiểm tra xem đã tìm thấy cổng Arduino chưa
if arduino_port is not None:
    print(f"Đã tìm thấy cổng Arduino: {arduino_port}")
else:
    print("Không tìm thấy cổng Arduino.")

    # Kết nối đến Arduino thông qua cổng Serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600)  # Thay đổi 'COM3' thành cổng COM mà bạn đang sử dụng

# Khởi tạo kết nối với camera Intel RealSense D435
pipeline = rs.pipeline()
config = rs.config()
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 640, 480, rs.format.bgr8, 30)
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.depth, 640, 480, rs.format.z16, 30)
pipeline.start(config)

target_x = 320
target_y = 240

# Khởi tạo PID cho tọa độ X và Y
pid_x = PID(Kp=0.1, Ki=0.01, Kd=0.05)
pid_y = PID(Kp=0.1, Ki=0.01, Kd=0.05)



try:
    while True:
        # Chờ và lấy một khung hình mới từ camera
        frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
        color_frame = frames.get_color_frame()
        depth_frame = frames.get_depth_frame()

        if not color_frame or not depth_frame:
            continue

        # Chuyển dữ liệu hình ảnh từ RealSense frame thành mảng NumPy
        color_image = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())

        # Vẽ hai đường thẳng vuông góc
        cv2.line(color_image, (target_x, 0), (target_x, 480), (0, 0, 255), 2)  # Đường thẳng dọc
        cv2.line(color_image, (0, target_y), (640, target_y), (0, 0, 255), 2)  # Đường thẳng ngang

        # Hiển thị màn hình dự thay đổi
        cv2.imshow("Color Image", color_image)

        # Làm mờ ảnh để giảm nhiễu
        blurred_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(color_image, (15, 15), 0)

        # Chuyển ảnh sang ảnh xám để tăng hiệu suất xử lý
        gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(blurred_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Tìm vòng tròn trong ảnh
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(
            gray_image,
            cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,
            dp=1,
            minDist=20,
            param1=50,
            param2=30,
            minRadius=0,
            maxRadius=0
        )

        if circles is not None:
            circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

            for circle in circles[0, :]:
                # Lấy tọa độ tâm và bán kính của vòng tròn
                x, y, radius = circle

                depth_width = depth_frame.get_width()
                depth_height = depth_frame.get_height()

                if 0 <= x < depth_width and 0 <= y < depth_height:
                    depth_at_center = depth_frame.get_distance(x, y)
                    depth_at_center_mm = depth_at_center * 1000  # Chuyển đổi sang milimet

                    # In ra tọa độ tâm x, y
                    print(f"Tọa độ tâm (x, y): ({x}, {y}")

                    # Tiếp tục xử lý dữ liệu độ sâu
                else:
                    print("Tọa độ (x, y) nằm ngoài phạm vi hợp lệ của ảnh độ sâu.")

                # Hiển thị độ sâu trên màn hình màu
                depth_text = "     {:.2f} mm".format(depth_at_center_mm)
                cv2.putText(color_image, depth_text, (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)



                # Khai báo thông số nội của camera
                depth_intrin = rs.intrinsics()

                # Đặt thông số nội của camera
                depth_intrin.width = 640  # Thay thế bằng kích thước ảnh của bạn
                depth_intrin.height = 480  # Thay thế bằng kích thước ảnh của bạn
                depth_intrin.ppx = 320  # Điểm trung tâm ảnh theo trục x
                depth_intrin.ppy = 240  # Điểm trung tâm ảnh theo trục y
                depth_intrin.fx = 450.0  # Độ dốc theo trục x (focal length x)
                depth_intrin.fy = 450.0  # Độ dốc theo trục y (focal length y)

                # Độ sâu của tâm hình tròn
                depth_value = depth_at_center_mm  # Thay thế bằng độ sâu của tâm hình tròn

                # Tính toán tọa độ 3D
                depth_point = rs.rs2_deproject_pixel_to_point(depth_intrin, [x, y], depth_value)

                # In tọa độ 3D của tâm hình tròn
                print("Tọa độ 3D của tâm hình tròn (X, Y, Z):", depth_point)





                # Tính sai lệch tọa độ ảnh màu và tọa độ 3D
                error_x = target_x - x
                error_y = target_y - y

                # Sử dụng PID để tính điều khiển
                control_x = pid_x(error_x)
                control_y = pid_y(error_y)

                # Điều khiển tọa độ của tâm hình tròn dựa trên sai số và điều khiển PID
                new_x = x + int(control_x)
                new_y = y + int(control_y)

                # Giới hạn tọa độ mới trong phạm vi khung hình
                new_x = max(0, min(new_x, 639))
                new_y = max(0, min(new_y, 479))

                # Vẽ vòng tròn và tâm trên ảnh màu
                cv2.circle(color_image, (x, y), radius, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                cv2.circle(color_image, (x, y), 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)

                # Gửi tọa độ mới tới Arduino qua cổng serial
                ser.write(f'{new_x},{new_y}\n'.encode())



            # Hiển thị ảnh kết quả
            cv2.imshow('Detected Circles with Depth', color_image)

        # Đợi phím nhấn 'q' để thoát khỏi vòng lặp
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

finally:
    # Đóng kết nối và dọn dẹp
    pipeline.stop()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    ser.close()  # Đóng kết nối Serial với Arduino
```

And here is the code arduino:

````
#include <AccelStepper.h>

// Khai báo các chân kết nối đến động cơ bước
int STP = 2;
int DIR = 5;
int ENA = 8;

int STP2 = 3;
int DIR2 = 6;



// Khởi tạo đối tượng động cơ bước cho động cơ X và Y
AccelStepper stepperX(AccelStepper::DRIVER, STP, DIR, ENA);
AccelStepper stepperY(AccelStepper::DRIVER, STP2, DIR2, ENA);


void setup() {
  
  pinMode(ENA, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ENA, LOW);
  
  // Cài đặt tốc độ và các thông số động cơ bước
  stepperX.setMaxSpeed(2000);
  stepperX.setAcceleration(1000);
  stepperY.setMaxSpeed(2000);
  stepperY.setAcceleration(1000);
  
  
  // Mở kết nối Serial
  Serial.begin(9600);
   
}



void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // Đọc dữ liệu từ serial port
    String data = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');

    // Tách giá trị new_x và new_y từ chuỗi dữ liệu
    int commaIndex = data.indexOf(',');
    if (commaIndex != -1) {
      String new_x_str = data.substring(0, commaIndex);
      String new_y_str = data.substring(commaIndex + 1);

      // Chuyển đổi giá trị new_x và new_y thành kiểu số nguyên
      int new_x = new_x_str.toInt();
      int new_y = new_y_str.toInt();

      // Điều khiển stepper1 và stepper2 dựa trên giá trị new_x và new_y
      stepperX.moveTo(new_x);
      stepperX.run();
      stepperY.moveTo(new_y);
      stepperY.run();
      
    }
  }
}
```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.